# php isn't emailing form. Where can I find my php errors in cpanel

Tags: php

Hey guys I have a quote form that isn't getting emailed to the business owner and I can't figure out where the php errors can be viewed. I read some instructions that told me to edit the php.ini file and turn error logging on but I couldn't find that file. Then someone on SO told me that error logging should already be enabled and that it would be in the logs folder that sits in the public_html folder. Then within the logs folder there is an error_logs folder and The errors were gonna be there. I found it and opened it and its blank nothing is in there? I speculate that its because I didn't try to submit/email the broken form? Anyway I need help with this I have to find the issue and fix it today whilst having no php experience(don't ask)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get useful error messages in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-can-i-get-useful-error-messages-in-php) and [How do I get PHP errors to display?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1053424/1839439)

Comment: Add code to the question

Answer (score 0):

You can add the lines below to the top of your PHP file to display errors in the browser:

```php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

See: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: go to www.gilbertmovingandstorage.com  I added this code and there's no php errors in the console

Comment: try filling out the form and submitting it

Comment: That means that there's no PHP error. Try these step then: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24644436/php-mail-function-doesnt-complete-sending-of-e-mail